# android rss feed reader issues

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

**I want to developer RSS FEED reader for android. I am following this tutorial** http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-androidrss/downloads.html

I am not getting any error in the program but not getting desired output

**This is my logcat:**

```
07-20 16:12:23.531: ERROR/Zygote(33): setreuid() failed. errno: 2
07-20 16:12:35.101: ERROR/Zygote(33): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
07-20 16:12:37.031: ERROR/BatteryService(59): usbOnlinePath not found
07-20 16:12:37.031: ERROR/BatteryService(59): batteryVoltagePath not found
07-20 16:12:37.031: ERROR/BatteryService(59): batteryTemperaturePath not found
07-20 16:12:37.061: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(59): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
07-20 16:12:47.381: ERROR/EventHub(59): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
07-20 16:12:47.412: ERROR/EventHub(59): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
07-20 16:12:47.812: ERROR/System(59): Failure starting core service
07-20 16:12:47.812: ERROR/System(59): java.lang.SecurityException
07-20 16:12:47.812: ERROR/System(59):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
07-20 16:12:47.812: ERROR/System(59):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
07-20 16:12:47.812: ERROR/System(59):     at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
07-20 16:12:47.812: ERROR/System(59):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:184)
07-20 16:12:49.591: ERROR/SoundPool(59): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-20 16:12:49.591: ERROR/SoundPool(59): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
07-20 16:12:49.602: ERROR/SoundPool(59): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
07-20 16:12:49.612: ERROR/SoundPool(59): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
07-20 16:12:49.622: ERROR/SoundPool(59): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
07-20 16:12:52.672: ERROR/ThrottleService(59): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
07-20 16:12:54.551: ERROR/logwrapper(145): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
07-20 16:12:54.691: ERROR/logwrapper(147): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
07-20 16:12:54.781: ERROR/logwrapper(149): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
07-20 16:13:17.789: ERROR/HierarchicalStateMachine(59): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
07-20 16:13:38.669: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Start proc com.svox.pico for broadcast com.svox.pico/.VoiceDataInstallerReceiver: pid=268 uid=10028 gids={}
07-20 16:13:38.689: WARN/RecognitionManagerService(59): no available voice recognition services found
07-20 16:13:39.370: DEBUG/dalvikvm(59): GC_EXPLICIT freed 9347 objects / 593752 bytes in 302ms
07-20 16:13:39.590: DEBUG/dalvikvm(165): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2883 objects / 156272 bytes in 1275ms
07-20 16:13:39.659: INFO/installd(35): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.msi.androidrss-1.apk@classes.dex
07-20 16:13:39.782: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(118): Shutting down VM
07-20 16:13:39.789: DEBUG/jdwp(118): adbd disconnected
07-20 16:13:39.809: INFO/AndroidRuntime(118): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
07-20 16:13:39.879: INFO/ActivityThread(268): Publishing provider com.svox.pico.providers.SettingsProvider: com.svox.pico.providers.SettingsProvider
07-20 16:13:40.131: DEBUG/KeyguardViewMediator(59): pokeWakelock(5000)
07-20 16:13:40.429: DEBUG/KeyguardViewMediator(59): pokeWakelock(5000)
07-20 16:13:40.511: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(278): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
07-20 16:13:40.511: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(278): CheckJNI is ON
07-20 16:13:41.740: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher: 50234 ms (total 50234 ms)
07-20 16:13:42.340: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(278): --- registering native functions ---
07-20 16:13:43.790: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.msi.androidrss/.ShowDescription }
07-20 16:13:43.890: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(278): Shutting down VM
07-20 16:13:43.910: DEBUG/jdwp(278): adbd disconnected
07-20 16:13:43.960: INFO/AndroidRuntime(278): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
07-20 16:13:44.099: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Start proc com.msi.androidrss for activity com.msi.androidrss/.ShowDescription: pid=286 uid=10042 gids={1015}
07-20 16:13:45.939: INFO/ARMAssembler(59): generated scanline__00000077:03545404_00000004_00000000 [ 47 ipp] (67 ins) at [0x2ff7e0:0x2ff8ec] in 7962326 ns
07-20 16:13:46.670: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.msi.androidrss/.ShowDescription: 2691 ms (total 2691 ms)
```

**This is my manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.msi.androidrss"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">


    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".ShowDescription"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

**This is one of my .java program "RSSReader.java"**

```
package com.msi.androidrss;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener; 
import android.util.Log;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

import android.content.Intent;

import com.msi.androidrss.ShowDescription;

public class RSSReader extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener
{

    public final String RSSFEEDOFCHOICE = "http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/views/rss/customrssatom.jsp?zone_by=XML&zone_by=Java&zone_by=Rational&zone_by=Linux&zone_by=Open+source&zone_by=WebSphere&type_by=Tutorials&search_by=&day=1&month=06&year=2007&max_entries=20&feed_by=rss&isGUI=true&Submit.x=48&Submit.y=14";

    private static final int SELECT = 0;
    private static final int REFRESH = 1;

    public final String tag = "RSSReader";
    private RSSFeed feed = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // go get our feed!
        feed = getFeed(RSSFEEDOFCHOICE);

        // display UI
        UpdateDisplay();

    }


    private RSSFeed getFeed(String urlToRssFeed)
    {
        try
        {
            // setup the url
           URL url = new URL(urlToRssFeed);

           // create the factory
           SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
           // create a parser
           SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

           // create the reader (scanner)
           XMLReader xmlreader = parser.getXMLReader();
           // instantiate our handler
           RSSHandler theRssHandler = new RSSHandler();
           // assign our handler
           xmlreader.setContentHandler(theRssHandler);
           // get our data via the url class
           InputSource is = new InputSource(url.openStream());
           // perform the synchronous parse           
           xmlreader.parse(is);
           // get the results - should be a fully populated RSSFeed instance, or null on error
           return theRssHandler.getFeed();
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            // if we have a problem, simply return null
            return null;
        }
    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
     menu.add(0, RSSReader.SELECT, 0, "Choose RSS Feed").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_mapmode);
        //menu.add(0,0,"Choose RSS Feed");
        //menu.add(0,1,"Refresh");
     menu.add(0, RSSReader.REFRESH, 0, "Refresh").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_mapmode);
        Log.i(tag,"onCreateOptionsMenu");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(final int featureId, final MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case RSSReader.SELECT:

            Log.i(tag,"Set RSS Feed");
            return true;
        case RSSReader.REFRESH:
            Log.i(tag,"Refreshing RSS Feed");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    private void UpdateDisplay()
    {
        TextView feedtitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.feedtitle);
        TextView feedpubdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.feedpubdate);
        ListView itemlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemlist);


        if (feed == null)
        {
            feedtitle.setText("No RSS Feed Available");
            return;
        }

        feedtitle.setText(feed.getTitle());
        feedpubdate.setText(feed.getPubDate());

        ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RSSItem>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,feed.getAllItems());

        itemlist.setAdapter(adapter);

        itemlist.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        itemlist.setSelection(0);

    }




    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)

     {
         Log.i(tag,"item clicked! [" + feed.getItem(position).getTitle() + "]");

         Intent itemintent = new Intent(this,ShowDescription.class);

         Bundle b = new Bundle();
         b.putString("title", feed.getItem(position).getTitle());
         b.putString("description", feed.getItem(position).getDescription());
         b.putString("link", feed.getItem(position).getLink());
         b.putString("pubdate", feed.getItem(position).getPubDate());

         itemintent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT", b);

         startActivity(itemintent);
     }

}
```

**This is one of my .java program "ShowDescription.java"**

```
package com.msi.androidrss;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.*;

public class ShowDescription extends Activity 
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) 
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.showdescription);

        String theStory = null;


        Intent startingIntent = getIntent();

        if (startingIntent != null)
        {
            Bundle b = startingIntent.getBundleExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT");
            if (b == null)
            {
                theStory = "bad bundle?";
            }
            else
            {
                theStory = b.getString("title") + "\n\n" + b.getString("pubdate") + "\n\n" + b.getString("description").replace('\n',' ') + "\n\nMore information:\n" + b.getString("link");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            theStory = "Information Not Found.";

        }

        TextView db= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.storybox);
        db.setText(theStory);

        Button backbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);

        backbutton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                finish();
            }
        });        
    }
}
```

**As an output I am getting "*bad bundle*", why ?**

**HELP!!!**

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your logcat output you are starting your ShowDescription activity from the Launcher. If this is the case - no wonder it doesn't have any Extra in starting intent.

Because as far as the code goes that BundleExtra is being put in the starting intent only when this activity is started from RSSReader Activity.

Comment: So what needs to be done for solving this problem ? what's the solution ? (I also add my manifest file above)

Comment: The solution would be to put your RSSReader activity in manifest. This will make it appear in Android Launcher. And then you start it and press on item in list - this will trigger RSSReader.onItemClicked() which in turn will create intent, put bundle in it and then start your ShowDescription Activity. At least try it - that's what I see in code. Maybe you'll need some more adjustements to get it working, but I hope you'll succeed after a few tries :) If not, write about your problems here we'll try to help :)

Comment: thanks. sorry I am new in android dev. so I need to remove "activity android:name=".ShowDescription"
" and change it with RSSReader activity right ? what else about bundle? can you plz show me with code ? plz

Comment: Sorry no time for full blown example right now (maybe someone else?). But simply replaceing .ShowDescription with .RSSActivity should work. This tells android which activity to laucnh when you press app icon in your phone's laucnher. Logic is simple: you start RSSActivity, it has list. When item in list is clicked RSSActivity creates an Intent and puts some extra info (bundle) in it. then it uses it to laucnh another activity which extracts this info. Read some docs, do some experiments, read the code and I guess you'll figure it out :)

Comment: I did and not instead of "bad bundle" , I am getting **"NO RSS FEED AVAILABLE".** I tested it with few different rss feeds and getting same message. I am pretty sure the RSS feed i am using in this program is working, I tested in web browser. any help would be apprenticed.

Comment: Sorry, I can't solve every problem you have. Try using Log.d() here and there to see why feed variable isn't created. You'll learn more if you try to solve this yourself than if you'll be given answer for any tiny error you're seeing :) Happy hacking! :-)

Comment: Tried many times but still not able to figure out what the problem is. Can anyone direct me to the right direction ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have .RSSReader added to your manifest file, and also add this line to the manifest file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```